# Why is my python program not giving a correct file output?

Tags: python

Hello I am having trouble with my homework...I keep getting an error that I will post after my program.

**my program**

```
def create():

    myGrades_file = open('grades.txt','w')

    while True:

        my_courses = input("Enter course name or Enter to quit: ")

        if my_courses == '':

            print("File was created and closed")

            break

        my_grades = int(input("Enter grade (integer) achieved: "))

        string = my_courses+','+" "+str(my_grades)+'\n'

        myGrades_file.write(string)

    myGrades_file.close()

    return True

def retrieve():

    print("\nHere are your grades:")

    grades_total = 0

    count = 0

    gpa=0    

    myGrades_file = open('grades.txt','r')

    for line in myGrades_file:

        mycourses, grades = line.strip().split(',')

        grades_total+=int(grades)

        if(int(grades)>=90):

            gpa+=4.0

        elif(int(grades)>=80):

            gpa+=3.0

        elif(int(grades)>=70):

            gpa+=2.0

        elif(int(grades)>=60):

            gpa+=1.0

        else:

            gpa+=0.0

        count+=1

        gpa_total = gpa/count

        print("{} score is{}".format(mycourses,grades))

    average = grades_total/count

    print("Average grade among your courses is {:.2f}".format(average),"Your GPA is {:.2f}".format(gpa_total))

    return average

def main():

    create()

    average = retrieve()

main()
```

I for some reason for the life of me cannot figure out what I am doing wrong!

**the error**

```
Test 2 Expected data: ['CGS1070', '98'] Data in file: ['CGS1070, 98']Test 2 FailedE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_2_io_case_2 (__main__.programTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['CGS1070, 98'] != ['CGS1070', '98']

First differing element 0:
'CGS1070, 98'
'CGS1070'

Second list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 1:
'98'

- ['CGS1070, 98']
+ ['CGS1070', '98']
?          +  +


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: Contents of file != Expected
```

Comment: When do you get the error? Cause I tried running the program and I had no issues. Is your indenting correct?

Comment: I will check the indenting...However everything looks exactly what the professor wants except the unitest says otherwise (this is where I receive the error )? it keeps saying that what is written in the grades.txt file is incorrect :/.

Comment: I suspect that there is an error in the grading system